# Cauchy integral formula or something else?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I need to determine the function $\;f(z)$ if
$$f''(z)=\oint_{\partial C_1(0)}{\sin^2\xi \over\left(\xi-z\right)^3}\mathbb{d}\xi$$

with $C_1(0):\left|z\right|<1$ positive. Additionally $\;f(0)=0,\;f'(0)=2$.

I am stuck on the integral. Quite obvious they want me to apply Cauchy's integral formula. However I am not sure how I can handle this with the integrand $\xi$. Is there some substitution to be made or anything else?

Comment: If you don't like the variable $\xi$, then replace it with something nicer.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I am not confused with $xi$ itself but with the differential operator $\mathbb{d} \xi$. Cauchy's integral formula would be good if there stayed $\mathbb{d} z$, or am I missing something?

Comment: @DmitryKazakov The name of the integration variable is irrelevant. What you have there is, modulo a normalising factor, the integral formula for the second derivative of (some function).

Comment: @DanielFischer due to some unknown reason I was thinking that the variable in $|z|<1$ should correspond to the variable staying after $\mathbb{d}$. Need definitely make a break, thanks, got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Just rename variables, does $$f''(a)=\oint_{\partial C_1(0)}{\sin^2z \over\left(z-a\right)^3}\mathbb{d}z$$ look at all familiar?

Comment: God, that's so stupid of me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

compare $$f''(a)=\oint_{\partial C_1(0)}{\sin^2z \over\left(z-a\right)^3}\mathbb{d}z$$ and $$f''(a)=\frac{2!}{2 \pi  i}\oint_{\partial C_1(0)}{f(z) \over\left(z-a\right)^3}\mathbb{d}z$$